# Is there a way to send contents of a web page you are looking at via email

Tags: email, internet

We live in a place where we have a slow internet connection and get charged per MB.  We have unlimited access to email though.  Is there an easy way for somebody to send us the contents of a web page (news article) they are on other than copying and pasting the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They could use FireFox [Send Page By Email](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2343) addon...

Answer (score 1):

Safari has menu a menu command for sending the contents of the page via email. At least it does on the Mac. You could see if Safari for Windows has the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

amusingly enough, [uucp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUCP) was designed to do just that ([and some still use it that way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizzy_Digital_Courier)). I suppose you could use [httrack](http://www.httrack.com/) to spider a certain depth down, alternately. Of course, this is assuming your 'free' e mail will let you accept reasonably sized attachments

Answer (score 0):

I like archiving pages to .PDF format, even though I usually don't mail them.

Chrome has a Print to PDF option that can convert most webpages into PDF format.  Also, [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/) allows you to have a "PDF printer" that can be used by any application.